# How to log out a google account from an Android app

Tags: android, google-authentication

I am working on an Android app which uses google authentication.
I have this code segment:

```
try {
    String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(main, id, "oauth2:profile");
    TRC.debug("google token=" + token);
    return token;
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
    main.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), 15); // TODO const for 15
```

I would like to test the catch branch. When I've tried it first I got the google authentication Activity displayed. But when I tried it next time the UserRecoverableAuthException hadn't thrown.

How is it possible to force the app to log out from google?

Comment: Have you tried [clearing](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#clearToken(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) the token? 
`GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken(main, token);`

Comment: I have tried. It doesn't seem to be effective. The getToken() returns with different token every time. So I don't think that a cached token is reused.